# Why does C++ not differentiate between pass by reference and pass by value in syntax?

Tags: c++, reference

Consider I have this function:

```
foo(int &x1, int x2);
```

And someone is calling it like this:

```
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    foo(x, x);
}
```

When you only look at the main function, you cannot see, that the first value is passed by reference and the second is passed by value. Why isn't there some additional syntax to "avoid this problem"? Example:

```
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    foo(*x, x);
}
```

I don't really know, why the C++ syntax is specified like this. I could imagine there is a reason behind this, I can't get, because I don't saw a good Use-Case before.

Edit:
The possible duplicate question is dealing with pass-by-reference and pass-by-pointer. My question is about, why pass-by-reference and pass-by-**value** do have the same callee syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out parameters and pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028413/out-parameters-and-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Another practically same question: [Is there a way to make passing by reference, and passing by value explicit in the function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19800841/580083).

Comment: `foo(*x, x);` would be a breaking change. Interestingly I don't think  `foo(x&, x);` would be. As for the question in hand, I think it's too late now - yes I agree it would be nice to know at the calling site whether or not a parameter could be modified.

Comment: @Bathsheba Unless you are writing generic code, where having to indicate it would mean yet more variants to write.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Clearly it would have to be annotational, rather like `override` and `final` otherwise all hell would break loose.

Comment: The question is too vague...

Comment: @anastaciu yes, this is the reason why it was closed?

Comment: You should perhaps improve it then...

Comment: @anastaciu For what? Maybe I forget to accept the answer, but I got a an aswer which was useful for me.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, just messing with you a bit, wasn't happy with that downvote, I was a bit triggered, sorry about that, hope there's no hard feelings.

Comment: @anastaciu As we germans say: the wiser head gives in. And that was you, we had a discussion, there where no insults from you or something for to apologize, but maybe I have to apologize, too

Comment: Nice civilised style, both of you. Happy to read something like this. Have fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, it is either obvious (it's obviously an out-argument, or obviously needs the original), or inconsequential (it's just an optimization) whether an argument is passed by reference instead of by value. The rest of the time, the API is either ill-designed, or you really should care what you are doing and read the manual / intellisense / headers.

But that's not the reason explicit marking of reference-arguments (that means in the calling code) would be a huge hindrance:
The magic word is `template`.

C++ templates are much more expressive than C#/Java style generics, they form their own turing-complete language. Writing more complicated templates can be difficult enough without having to cater to "this might be a ref-argument", and writing the additional variants to mark that.

An example template:

```
template <class T>
void logged_store(T&& t) {
    std::log << "storing \"" << t << "\"\n";
    storage.store(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

If `t` is a fundamental type (pointer, integer, float, ...), it would be passed by value to the stream-inserter.
If `t` is anything else, it would likely be passed by constant reference to avoid useless copies.

Comment: Until now, I never programmed with templates, but I can imagine the hazzle. Could you provide a small example, which shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will suit your needs since it is not a *syntax imposed by the language*. However, you might indicate *passing-by-reference* at a caller's side by using a *reference wrapper*. A solution with a *standard reference wrapper* has a drawback that it can be, in fact, used in both cases:

```
foo(std::ref(x), std::ref(x));  // no error
```

This is caused by the implicit conversion from `int&` to `int`.

However, you can create a custom reference wrapper that would allow casting into the stored reference type, but prevent casing into the corresponding value type. A basic exemplary implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class reference_wrapper
{
  T& ref_;
public:
  reference_wrapper(T& ref) : ref_(ref) { }
  operator T&() const { return ref_; }
  operator T() = delete;
};

template <typename T>
auto ref(T& ref) { return reference_wrapper<T>{ref}; }
```

Now, this reference wrapper cannot be used in the pass-by-value context:

```
int x = 1;
foo(std::ref(x), std::ref(x));  // ok
foo(ref(x), ref(x));            // error
foo(ref(x), x);                 // ok
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/OJJ2hj6F3PB7QzG2.

Note that compilers seem to be clever enough to optimize all the overhead away: https://godbolt.org/z/NiS119.

Comment: Just guessing, but I think having a reference without explicit notation at the call-site is the "problem", not the other way around. Also, this uses up the one allowed implicit custom conversion, which might be inconvenient.